# Update one column value with another column value using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I have a table which has three columns with integer values. In first two columns I have some values. Now I need to update the third column with the value which is minimum of other two columns.
I have tried using

```
update table set col3 = (SELECT CASE WHEN (col2 is null OR col1 < col2 )
THEN col1
ELSE col2
END AS col3
FROM  table 
WHERE col1 is not null or col2 is not null)`.
```

But I am getting an error like below:

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEAST` in order to update:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET col3 = LEAST(COALESCE(col1, col2), COALESCE(col2, col1))
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 IS NOT NULL
```

You don't have to query your table table to get `col2`, `col1` values. You can use them directly in the `SET` part of your `UPDATE` query.

**Note:** `COALESCE` is used to handle `NULL` values. If both `col1`, `col2` are `NULL` then `col3` is also set to `NULL`.

In SQL Server you can use:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET col3 = CASE 
              WHEN col2 IS NULL OR col1 < col2 THEN col1 
              ELSE col2
           END
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 IS NOT NULL
```

In SQL Server 2012, or later, you can use `IIF`:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET col3 = IIF(col2 IS NULL OR col1 < col2, col1, col2)
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 IS NOT NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be7f84/1)

Comment: But, in SQL it is showing that 'LEAST' function is not a built-in function

Comment: `LEAST` is a function of MySQL. You have tagged your question with this RDBMS. Are you on another platform?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Giorgos Betsos. The problem in my query is I have used SELECT before the CASE condition. So it is returning all row's column values which is not intended, by removing the SELECT it is returning only the value of the current row's column.

Comment: @SaikiranGosikonda Yes, exactly. The `UPDATE` is performed using the *current row's* column. Isn't this your intention?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join to the table it self, you can use the data from the columns in the same query

```
update table
set col3 = CASE WHEN (col2 is null OR col1 < col2 )
           THEN col1 ELSE col2 END  
WHERE col1 is not null or col2 is not null
```

The problem with your query is that you are using a correlated query, that selects col1 and col2(which is basically fine but unnecessary) and you are not filtering the results(which col1,col2 to take?) so for each col3 you want to update, you have a 'bunch' of other values, when you can only have 1. If you want your query to work all you have to do is add a relation condition.